# Should we seek the "Good Eye"?

Tags: superstition, ayin-hara-evil-eye

Traditional sources abound with exhortations to avoid the "evil eye" [Bava Metzia 107b and 85a, Pesachim 50b, Berakhot 55b, Bava Batra 2b and 141a].  The Talmud asserts flatly: "Damage caused by looking is also damage."  [Bava Batra 2b]

But there is also the "good eye" to counterbalance the evil eye.  It belongs to one who is satisfied with what he has and does not covet what others have.  The Mishna says:

> Whoever possesses these three things, he is of the disciples of Abraham, our father : ... a good eye, a humble spirit and a moderate appetite. [Avot 5:19]

Should you seek people who have a "good eye" (for example, your parents, who will rejoice at your good fortune and not envy it) so they may reinforce your blessings and perhaps invite more of the same?

I did not find such encouragement in the Sources -- only exhortations to avoid the evil eye.  Perhaps the answer is obvious.  But if so, isn't it also obvious in the case of the evil eye?

Comment: It appears that those two are completely unrelated and applied in different realms.

Answer (score 2):

[Mishlei 22:9](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%98) suggests

> טוֹב עַיִן הוּא יְבֹרָךְ
>
> That you are blessed through your own Good Eye.

See also, brought in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch

וראוי לכבד בברכת המזון למי שהוא טוב עין שונא בצע וגומל חסד בממונו שנאמר אפילו כל טוב עין הוא יבורך א"ת יבורך אלא יברך

It is appropriate to honour someone who has a Good Eye to say grace after meals.. as it says - one with a Good Eye will be blessed, do not read - will be blessed - but rather - he will bless.

This lends credence to your suggestion that one should seek blessing from someone with a Good Eye.